# How to safely store SVGs in a database and deliver as downloads?

Tags: php, wordpress, svg

I'm building a WordPress website that will serve SVG files for download. Since WP doesn't natively support uploading SVG for security reasons, I've opted for a custom text field where I copy-paste the SVG code, save it into the database, then pull that field data to display the SVG on the front-end of the site.

This JS then delivers the inline SVG to users who wish to download it:

```
$("#download-link").click((function() {
        var e = $(this)
          , t = $(".inline-svg").html()
          , i = new Blob([t],{
            type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"
        })
          , o = URL.createObjectURL(i);
        e.attr("href", o)
    }
))
```

**My question is**: is this a safe method for storing and delivering SVGs or am I overlooking other security concerns? Is this better/worse than just modifying WP in functions.php to allow upload of actual SVG files? FWIW, I will be the only creator of the SVGs as well as the only Admin of the site.

Comment: You can add hook to WP to allow upload SVG. To save it in DB will make DB slow, bloat.

Comment: @vee thanks, I should have mentioned the SVGs themselves are roughly 2,000 characters in size for reference. Main question is which method of serving (via DB or as SVG image files) is better from a security standpoint.

Comment: From my comment, I will never put file contents into DB as explained above. So, about the security - I have no idea but since it is a file then NO never in DB.

Comment: I guess if you save it as a string, it's gonna be as safe as strings usually are in a DB: But I too, would advise against saving them in a DB. I assume it might make your life harder.

Comment: The security concern WP has when it comes to uploading SVG is likely that they could probably contain scripting code. If _all_ users of your site could upload SVG, for example as their profile pic, that would be a possible attack vector (against other users, that get served those files, or maybe even against the admin area, when files are viewed there.) But if you implement it in a way that only you can upload them, and you know what they contain ... I would go with the default WP upload functionality.

Comment: SVG use XML format. They can have XSS attack ( https://blog.online-convert.com/svg-file-and-its-danger/ ). To prevent that, you can use sanitizer to clean it. Search for WordPress XSS sanitizer or looking for another sanitizer on GitHub, packagist, etc.

Comment: You may try [this](https://github.com/darylldoyle/svg-sanitizer), or [HTML purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) but I'm not sure does it work with SVG/XML.

Comment: Thank you all for the helpful feedback on simply using SVG images over delivering via the DB. One final question: knowing that I'll be the only Admin (actually, the only User on the whole site), what are any remaining security concerns with uploading SVGs as files as WordPress media? Any tips on ensuring those are safe to store/use would be appreciated!

Comment: If SVG you are using is not created by you or not created by the software that is **safe** (use crack, have virus, etc means not safe) then it is cannot be trusted. Always sanitize it first.